# Configure Logic App Management with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm

I am trying to configure Logic App Management for a series of Logic Apps that I maintaining in Azure, following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics) the way my permissions are configured, this type of resource can only be provisioned at the Service Principal level.

I have tried browsing Terraform's [AzureRM provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/3.37.0). It doesn't appear to be immediately obvious that there is a way to configure Logic App Management via terraform. I checked the [AzureRM Logic Apps Resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_standard) as well as the [Log Analytics Workspace Resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_workspace) and it doesn't appear that there is a way to configure that within Terraform. Has anyone had to do this with Terraform or know of a way to do this?

Note: I do understand that Logic App Management is in "Preview" mode but would like to stick to the standard of managing infrastructure and resources with IaC

Answer (score 0):

Of course as soon as I ask, I end up stumbling on the solution so figured I would add the answer here. It appears that there is a [Log Analytics Solution](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/log_analytics_solution) block that can be provisioned within terraform. With a list of solutions that one can provision linked in the article. Hopefully this is a satisfactory answer with a link to the Terraform docs, if anyone wants anymore information please comment on this answer and I'd be happy to inform!